# Suspending Script Immediately

Tags: autohotkey, suspend

```
Suspend, on

Esc::ExitApp
LCtrl::suspend

SetTimer, Close, 5000
SetTimer, Open, 5000
SetTitleMatchMode, 2

Close:
IfWinNotExist, Notepad
Msgbox, NotDetected
Return

Open:
IfWinExist, Notepad
Msgbox, Detected
Return
```

The above script does not behave as I would expect. I would expect that when it loads, it is suspended immediately (it does this). I would then expect that when I toggle suspend, a message box is displayed every 5s depending whether notepad.exe is open.

What actually happens is that it loads suspended, but when I toggle suspend, nothing happens.

What am I doing incorrectly here to have the Open/Close loop every 5s after toggling suspend.

Answer (score 0):

Going to leave this here for posterity.

There's a difference between "suspend" and "pause" - one handles hotkeys, the other is the actual script thread. I needed the latter.